# input focus placeholder top not working on input readonly and placeholder

Tags: html, css, focus, css-transitions

I have created a input box like these:

[image]

but when I use input box readonly it is not working.
Here is my working snippet:

```css
.myinput input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.myinput {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.myinput .inputText {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: unset !important;
}

.myinput .inputText:focus {
  border-color: #3399FF;
  border-width: medium medium 2px;
}

.myinput .floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  color: #aaa;
}

.myinput input:focus~.floating-label,
.myinput input:not(:focus):valid~.floating-label,
.myinput input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus):valid + .floating-label,{
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #3399FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="myinput">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="coupon" class="inputText" value="Test" placeholder="" readonly>
  <span class="floating-label">Enter Coupon Code</span>
</div>
```

When i removed `required` option from AddressLine2 input field it focused on top. See image below:

[image]

Want to fix the readonly and placeholder isseus!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `:read-only` pseudo-selector to make the placeholder move to the top.

`.myinput input:read-only + .floating-label`

**Note:** you can replace the general sibling `~` combinator with the adjacent sibling `+` combinator, since the `.floating-label` comes right after the input.

**Example:**

```css
.myinput input:focus {
  outline: none;
}

.myinput {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}

.myinput .inputText {
  width: 100%;
  outline: none;
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  box-shadow: none !important;
  border-radius: unset !important;
}

.myinput .inputText:focus {
  border-color: #3399FF;
  border-width: medium medium 2px;
}

.myinput .floating-label {
  position: absolute;
  pointer-events: none;
  top: 25px;
  left: 0;
  transition: 0.2s ease all;
  color: #aaa;
}

.myinput input:focus + .floating-label,
.myinput input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus):valid + .floating-label,
.myinput input:read-only + .floating-label {
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  font-size: 13px;
  opacity: 1;
  color: #3399FF;
}
```

```html
<div class="myinput">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="coupon" class="inputText" value="Read Only" placeholder="" readonly>
  <span class="floating-label">Enter Coupon Code</span>
</div>

<div class="myinput">
  <br>
  <input type="text" name="coupon" class="inputText" placeholder="&nbsp;">
  <span class="floating-label">Enter Coupon Code</span>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks it works for me one another thing when i removed required from input field it will not works properly the label text is fixed. how to fix this? @Ori Drori

Comment: The problem is how to know that the input is empty. One option is to use the `:valid` rule, and that requires `required`. The other option is to use pseudo-selector `:placeholder-shown`, but then the placeholder shouldn't be empty - I've used `nbsp;`.

Comment: The answer works without required now - `.myinput input:not(:placeholder-shown):not(:focus):valid + .floating-label,`, and `placeholder="&nbps;"`.

Comment: but i want both with and without require see my last image in address line2 this option is not required but it focused always with using these style

Comment: Add `placeholder="&nbps;"` to the input, so the placeholder would be used, when no value exists.

Comment: thanks man it works now I got your point and understand about this. Can you please share the latest css effects with me than i can learn those

Comment: Enjoy - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-classes

Answer (score 0):

this is read only but the span tag below already takes that class and display over the input if you are trying to write this code as an component and using this in several places you should make it dynamic with javascript but if you are repeat this code every time you should change that classname of your span tag.